# Try to use importxml to get the GDP data from wiki, but can't make it

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I want to get the US GDP data from wiki, with the following code, but can't make it.

```
=importxml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate","//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table/tbody/tr[137]/td[3]")
```

it returns "N/A", tried many many times, so frustrated.
Can anybody help!?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate","table")
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate","//tr[138]/td[@align = 'center']")
```

Comment: Please give an explanation for better understanding.

Comment: @JosephKong please checkout [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)